# Adding Day Of week to file name in batch file

Tags: windows, batch

I want to run a daily incremental backup and append the day of the week to the file name so I end up with:

backup_mon.bak
backup_tue.bak

etc.

Not really bothered about what exactly is appended - 0 - 6 is fine.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using this for a backup, you are presumably running the script with admin privileges, in which case you can use wmic.

```
for /F "tokens=2 skip=2 delims=," %%D in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek /Format:csv') do @echo %%D
```

Will give you the day of week as a number (Monday=1).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Advanced date and time math](http://robvanderwoude.com/datetimentmath.php) in batch files. You find there a subroutine which converts a date to the Julian calendar and another one which will tell you the weekday.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problem calling an external script, you can use VBScript to get the day of week very easily:

the VBScript code:

```
wscript.echo WeekdayName(Weekday(Date))
```

Calling it and using it in your filename:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript /nologo dayofweek.vbs') do @set myvar=%%a
set filename=backup_%myvar%.bak
```

then later in your script you can use the variable `%filename%` to access it. If I ran this today for example, it would create a file called `backup_Sunday.bak`. Ensure the VBscript file is in the same directory as the batch script.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```bat
@echo off

for /f usebackq^tokens^=2^delims^=^,^  %%i in =;(`
     robocopy ^| findstr /v "\/ \\\\ - ::" ^| find ","`);= do set "_Name=%%~i"
```

---

**Obs.: 1** There are two spaces in:

```bat
...delims^=^,^SPACESPACE%%~i..

:: Or use "" :: 

for /f "tokens=3delims=, " %%i in ('robocopy^|findstr /e "AM PM"')do set "_Name=%%~i"
```

**Obs.: 2** Is a variation of **[Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386561/dan)** **[`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22215071/8177207)** without a comma `,` in the variable/outputs.